# FakeRAID array is failing, why?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, raid, raid-1

We have a Windows XP system with an AMD mainboard (GA-890GPA-UD3H) and we are using the onboard RAID capability.
The system is configured in RAID 1 (using the tool AMD RAIDXpert). It consists of two 500GB Samsung HD502IJ hard drives.

The problem is that the array is failing often. The error message given is: `Logical drive goes critical.` Therefore, the drives are not mirrored any more.

I can rebuild the drives, but this does not help a lot. The error repeats irregularly/erratically. Sometimes it fails after 3 days, sometimes after 7 days, so it's not stable.

What's the problem and how do I prove it?
I can get S.M.A.R.T information on the drives and they are fine individually.

Comment: It's a GA-890GPA-UD3H mainboard. It has two RAID controllers. Both of them fail.

Comment: SAMSUNG HD502IJ, those are the 2 hard drives

Comment: Yesterday I saw it: The first drive disconnected and it reconnected within a second, but the RAID was broken. But y did the first drive disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with consumer (WD and Hitachi) hard disks mounted in various NAS (with hardware RAID).

After many experiments, I found that my problem was related to different ways disks handle read delays and timeouts.

I had to enable TLER/CCTL on the drives firmware. Arrays worked flawlessly since then.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control

Comment: Sounds interesting. May be the problem. Do you know a tool to enable CCTL?

Comment: @vanCompute IIRC a tool called HDAT2 was used for Hitachi drives. Another person reconfigured Hitachi drivers, I worked only on WD ones, with the specific WDTLER utility. And keep in mind that unfortunately not every drive support altering the read timeout. It depends on model number and specific firmware revision. You'll have to try...

Answer (score 0):

I've had plenty of problems with Samsung drives and an AMD chipset (in a HP Microserver). It's a 780G chipset I believe.

I use Linux, and with high throughput on the drives i'll get log messages complaining the controller didn't respond in time and was reset. Eventually it ended up corrupting the array. Turning off AHCI and dropping down to SATA1 helped a bit, but didn't completely clear the issue.

A friend with the same hardware had the same problem on Windows Home Server, though I don't remember what the logs said.

Can you see anything in eventvwr about the drives?

Comment: I can see an event by AMD RAID API: Logical drive "myraid" goes critical due to disk(s)port 1 target 1 failure..

Comment: On Linux do you use [mdadm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm)? (Not related to my question.)

Comment: I do use mdadm, but it's not related to the problem - I got it when the array was broken up, too. The problem even persisted when I used freenas, so it doesn't look like a driver issue. I suspect there is a hardware issue with that chipset.

Comment: So, do you use a softraid, and it fails? Or a fake/host-raid?

Comment: Fails with mdadm raid as well as with the array broken up (no raid). Seems to be provoked by heavy throughput but not always, I had a period when it happened at boot every time too.

Comment: By the way, this looks like the same issue but it does say a new driver fixes the problem? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/fe1bb186-7bdf-4fb7-9b83-71169cd7e52f

Comment: I don't have storahci in Events Log so I think, this is not the problem.